# Load images referenced in css django 1.4 development

Tags: python, css, django

I am trying to load background image for my development environment through a css file. I have done the following:

- I have the following in my main_page.html  link rel="stylesheet" href="static/style.css" type="text/css"
- In settings.py i have the following:
  STATIC_ROOT = '/home/vinay/myfiles/django-projects/taf/gui/static/'
  STATIC_URL = '/static/'
  STATICFILES_DIRS = ()
  TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
  "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth", 
  "django.core.context_processors.debug","django.core.context_processors.i18n", "django.core.context_processors.media","django.core.context_processors.static", "django.core.context_processors.tz", "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",)
- Run python manage.py collectstatic
- style.css and bg.jpg is present in the static folder
- In style.css the bg.jpg is referenced as:
  background:url("../bg.jpg");
  Tried all possible combinations like
  background:url("bg.jpg");
  background:url("static/bg.jpg");
  background("/static/bg.jpg")
  But nothing seems to work. Also, the production server displays the following:
  [25/Oct/2012 01:31:35] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1364
  [25/Oct/2012 01:31:35] "GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 442
  [25/Oct/2012 01:31:35] "GET /static/logo.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 0

So, it looks like the it is not trying to get "bg.jpg", but logo is present in    main_page.html and its getting that image but not the image referenced by the css file.
why is it so?

- The url.py file contains only:
  (r'^$', main_page),

Comment: What happens when you open /static/logo.gif in the browser ? The production server should **not** rely on django to serve /static/. You should have an alias like Alias /static/ /path/to/static/. Your question title refers to the development server, but your post refers to "production server". Anyway, I recommend you read [surviving staticfiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#referring-to-static-files-in-templates) and django docs. You're not supposed to put static files manually in STATIC_ROOT !!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. when i run localhost:8000/static/logo.gif, it displays the logo. Also, the logo is displayed in the webpage so, there are no problems with files referred through the html but through the files refered by the css file. CSS itself is loaded but not the image specified in that css.I removed all the files from STATIC_ROOT and made the variable refer to an empty folder and so running python manage.py collectstatic created all the files in that folder.

Comment: @jpic I would like to reformat my question. Everything works through the html file, but the image referred by the css does not load.

Comment: Sorry i would like to inform that my environment is development not production

Comment: Ok, try background-image: url('logo.gif');

Comment: @jpic Yes when i do try background-image: url('logo.gif'); nothing happens no change..

Comment: Right click on the body, click "Inspect element". Select <body> in tho DOM inspector and look at the CSS. Also, you have a CSS problem, not a django problem.

Comment: @jpic I have this exact same problem. When I check the generated code the image URL is correct. If I copy and paste it shows the image. This is weird.

Comment: Did you read [surviving staticfiles](http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/30382323418/surviving-django-contrib-staticfiles-or-how-to-manage) ? Disclamer: I wrote this article because it is such a FAQ ... probably the docs have a problem, the docs has a too subjective point of view that I think is not pedagogic. I've seen this FAQ maybe half a hundred of times ...